# Doxygen multi-line comment after variable

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have documented a struct with doxygen syntax.

```
//! This struct contains some info
typedef struct myInfo
{
    int variable1;  //!< This is a very long text about my variable. This
                    //!< is a very long text about my variable.
} myInfo;
```

When I generate the html/chm output, the variable description contains one "<": "This is a very long text about my variable. This < is a very long text about my variable."

I'm using the current doxygen 1.8.11 and I have set MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO.

According to the [doxygen homepage](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) (see "Putting documentation after members") this should be working, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
//! This struct contains some info
typedef struct myInfo
{
    int variable1;  /**< This is a very long text about my variable. This
                         is a very long text about my variable.*/
} myInfo;
```

Then you will get a really "very long" text.

If you want a multi-line comment, put a `\n` at the end of each line.